# Most popular twitter hashtags

Tags: data-request, social-media

I am looking for a list of most popular twitter hashtags for the last one year. Popularity means the number of time a hashtag was used. I need at least 1 thousand of them (the more the better).

[Twitter API allows](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) me to get only 50 top hashtags. Does anyone know any open source resource that has this information?

Answer (score 2):

The Stanford Network Analysis Project ([SNAP](https://snap.stanford.edu/index.html)) has a dataset:

**[Volume Time Series of Memetracker Phrases and Twitter Hashtags](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/volumeseries.html)**

> Data contains the time series of the volume (the number of mention per hour) of 1,000 Memetracker phrases and 1,000 Twitter hashtags. Memetracker phrases are the 1,000 highest total volume phrases among 343 million phrases collected from Sep 2008 to Aug 2009. Twitter hashtags are the 1,000 highest total volume hashtags among 6 million hashtags from Jun to Dec 2009.

The data is from Jun to Dec 2009, so that may not meet your criteria.

Comment: thank you. 2009 is too old, but still better than nothing.